# How to create OpenSSL::PKey using a public key string?

Tags: ruby, openssl, jwt

How do I create an `OpenSSL::PKey` object initialized with the following public key string? End goal is to use the object to decode a JWT token using `ruby-jwt`.

I've tried the following:

```
public_key = ""-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n ...many characters... \n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" # I only have the public key

OpenSSL::PKey.read(key) # Gives ArgumentError: Could not parse PKey: no start line
OpenSSL::PKey.read(key.gsub("CERTIFICATE", "PUBLIC KEY")) # Gives ArgumentError: Could not parse PKey: ASN1 lib
```

Ultimate goal is to use it decoding JWT:

```
# example from docs
require 'jwt'

rsa_public => OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read(File.join(CERT_PATH, 'rsa-2048-public.pem')))
JWT.decode(token, rsa_public, true, { algorithm: "RS256", verify_iat: true })
```

Any ideas for initializing `OpenSSL::PKey` with public key string?

Comment: Is there an extra quotation mark at the beginning of your `public_key`?

Comment: Its not a public key; its a X.509 certificate: ***`BEGIN CERTIFICATE`***. Extract the public key from the certificate and use it instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't have a RSA public key directly, but a RSA certificate instead, which contains a public key, and it's pretty easy to extract:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'jwt'

cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n .... \n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
x509 = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(cert)

payload = JWT.decode(token, x509.public_key, true, { algorithm: "RS256", verify_iat: true })
```

Of course, this will only work if the token was signed with that certificate's corresponding private key. I.e. for a token created like this:

```
payload = { data: 'test' }

priv = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- .....-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
rsa_private = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(priv)
token = JWT.encode payload, rsa_private, 'RS256'
```

Comment: Thanks Seba, it works. I did wonder if I had a certificate instead of a RSA public key and tried it but I didn't know I needed to extract the key from it. New to this stuff and none of the guidelines I looked through mentions how these thing work/inter-related.